# proving $a\leq b\wedge b\leq c$ implies $a\leq c$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I wish to prove the following inequality: $a\leq b\wedge b\leq c\Longrightarrow a\leq c$.

I tried the following proof.

Proof:

From the trichotomy law we have,that $a\leq b\Longrightarrow\neg(b<a)$.

Also $b\leq c\Longrightarrow\neg(c<b)$.

But : $\neg(c<b)\Longrightarrow\neg(c<b)\vee\neg(b<a)\Longrightarrow\neg(c<b\wedge b<a)$, by using De Morgan.

And, since  $c<b\wedge b<a\Longrightarrow c<a$, we have $\neg(c<a)\Longrightarrow a\leq c$ ,by using the trichotomy law.

Comment: It seems like something that one would prove from axioms. What are the axioms you are using?

Answer (score 1):

From $\neg(c<b\wedge b<a),$ we cannot directly conclude that $\neg(c<a).$ Rather, the reverse implication is equivalent to transitivity.

A better way to proceed, I'd say, is to use/prove that $$x\le y\iff(x=y\vee x<y)$$ for real numbers $x$ and $y$. This will allow you to proceed directly by cases, each of which is almost trivial.

Comment: Why can,t we directly conclude that $\neg(c<a)$

Comment: Well, for example, $\neg(2<1\wedge1<3)$ is true, but $\neg(2<3)$ does not follow.